# What does mean state 1 in db.config.locks collection

Tags: mongodb

In my config.locks collection after unsucessfull migration to 2.4 version I have document like this:

```
{
"_id" : "configUpgrade",
"process" : "mongo10:27017:1369289803:1804289383",
"state" : 1,
"ts" : ObjectId("519db44b8436a4e1aa17b0a5"),
"when" : ISODate("2013-05-23T06:16:43.075Z"),
"who" : "mongo10:27017:1369289803:1804289383:mongosMain:846930886",
"why" : "upgrading config database to new format v4"
}
```

What does it mean state 1? I know that valid values for 'state' are 0,1 and 2. What each of them means?

Comment: What is your previous version?

Comment: I was upgrading from 2.2.3. Now my problem is solved. I discovered that I had someway corrupted configdb in one of my three config servers. I suppose that state are: 0 - not running, 1 - problem, 2 - running, but I will glad if somebody will confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in the state field indicates that a mongos has the lock. For version 2.0 and later, the value of an active lock is 2; for earlier versions the value is 1.
src: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-sharded-cluster-balancer/

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/config-database/#config.locks states:

> If a mongos holds the balancer lock, the state field has a value of 2, which means that balancer is active. The when field indicates when the balancer began the current operation.

Only through the source (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/s/type_locks.h#L231) I can find out what state 1 means:

> int _state;     // (M)  0: Unlocked | 1: Locks in contention | 2: Lock held

From what I understand, this is used to upgrade locks between the 2.2 and 2.4 versions of MongoDB.

Comment: I am running mongo version 2.6.4 and saw many entries in my config servers locks collection with state 1. Could you please tell why these entries are there. Also entries are different in different config server means ids are different